# at/in/on the same day

Tags: prepositions

I have a sentence like:

> We run the three programs __ the same day:

Choices are:

1) at

2) in

3) on

Which one is correct? You can suggest another better choice if any.

Comment: Which do you think is correct? Have you googled the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with prepositions is that they follow few rules, and what rules they do follow are riddled with exceptions.

What is idiomatic in U.S. English is

> We run the three programs on the same day

or

> We run the three programs the same day.